# I want to run this code in ecllipse it is run fine on codingBat.com

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

Given an array of ints, return true if the value 3 appears in the array exactly 3 times, and no 3's are next to each other.

```
haveThree({3, 1, 3, 1, 3}) → true
haveThree({3, 1, 3, 3}) → false
haveThree({3, 4, 3, 3, 4}) → false
```

---

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums)
{
      int count = 0;
          boolean isPerv3 = false;
          for(int i = 0 ; i < nums.length && count <= 3; i++)
          {
            if(nums[i] == 3)
            {
                if(isPerv3)
                    return false;
                else
                {
                    count++;
                    isPerv3 = true;
                }
            }
            else
                isPerv3 = false;
          }
          return (count == 3);
}
```

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: If you copy/pasted the code you posted into eclipse, clicked run, and expected results then please refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `ListIterator` object would be ideal for this case. This way you can compare the next value in a List with the previous value. You can keep a counter to check and see if there are three 3's in succession.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] test1 = { 3, 2, 5, 11, 11, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 };   // false
        int[] test2 = { 3, 3, 3, 8, 3, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 };     // false
        int[] test3 = { 3, 2, 5, 8, 3, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3 };     // false
        int[] test4 = { 3, 2, 5, 8, 3, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 };        // true
        System.out.println(haveThree(test1));
        System.out.println(haveThree(test2));
        System.out.println(haveThree(test3));
        System.out.println(haveThree(test4));

    }

    public static boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {

        int totalNumberOfThrees = 0;
        int threeInSuccessionCount = 0;
        boolean result = false;

        // convert to ArrayList
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            arrayList.add(nums[i]);
        }

        // use ListIterator to compare next value with previous value
        ListIterator<Integer> iterator = arrayList.listIterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer next = iterator.next();
            Integer previous = iterator.previous();
            // counts total number of 3's
            if (next.intValue() == 3) {
                totalNumberOfThrees++;
            }
            // if next and previous values == 3 then increase count by 1
            if (next.intValue() == 3 && previous.intValue() == 3) {
                threeInSuccessionCount++;
            } 
            // if next and previous values != 3 then reset counter
            else {
                threeInSuccessionCount = 0;
            }
            // if there are three consecutive 3's set threeInSuccessionCount == 3 
            // and then break from loop 
            if (threeInSuccessionCount == 3) {
                break;
            }
            iterator.next();
        }

        if (threeInSuccessionCount != 3 && totalNumberOfThrees >= 3) {
            result = true;

        } else {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
true
```

**Edit:**

To answer your question '*how do I call (within the main method) haveThree() if **not** declared static?*', you can declare a new instance of Test within the main method and then use this to call haveThree().

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] test1 = { 3, 2, 5, 11, 11, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 };   
    int[] test2 = { 3, 3, 3, 8, 3, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 };
    int[] test3 = { 3, 2, 5, 8, 3, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3 };
    int[] test4 = { 3, 2, 5, 8, 3, 11, 233, 22, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 }; 

    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test.haveThree(test1));
    System.out.println(test.haveThree(test2));
    System.out.println(test.haveThree(test3));
    System.out.println(test.haveThree(test4));

}
```

Comment: hi i am new to this site i dont know howto do upvoting or ticking.when i try to do voting it says you cant vote your own post..i am a job seaker  looking a carrier in java j2EE how  should i make my logical java strong. every time when i go the interview i found one program is diff and very difficult i am not able to solve that.. how to make core java Stronger..